# Ignoring items in collection with Automapper when mapping collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I am mapping an collection of items

```
var List<A> myCollection = new List<A>();

public class A
{
    bool HasChanges {get;set;}
}

var mappedCollection = Map(myCollection);
```

then I only want to map the items where HasChanges == true

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With Linq:

```
var mappedCollection = Map(myCollection.Where(x => x.HasChanges == true).ToList());
```

Comment: My example was simplified, which is the reason I want to use automapper, I map a collection that contains 3 collections, I only want the objets in each of those collections that have changes, and then the linq wont be pretty anymore

Comment: Linq is always pretty. Don't be harsh! ;) Please update your Question for an better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper has custom type converters:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

```
// this is your converter
public class ATypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, A>
{
    public A Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
          // implement conversion logic
    }
}

// add this in a bootstrapper in your app
Mapper.CreateMap<string, A>().ConvertUsing<ATypeConverter>();
```

now after you `Map` your objects it will convert them using your custom mapper, which will allow you to skip the items with change.